# is there any other ways to refine mesh size in particular place without making a partition?

Tags: corrosion, abaqus, meshing

[image]

I am currently making a corroded model in Abaqus, but not all locations are suffering from corrosion. As shown in the picture there are some parts (the blue parts) that do suffer from corrosion, so since the picture is only part of the overall bridge structure, I am wondering whether there exists many ways to make finer mesh size in corroded locations only without creating a partition?

Please comment if you know how to resolve this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem
I used partition and adjust the mesh seed size